# How to calculate missing point of triangle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, angle

I am about to develop a special animation where I want to rotate a triangle (given a specific **width angle**) around a circle (given a specific **radius**) given a specific **rotationAngle**.

[image: img]

This is how I can calculate the 2 coordinates `x1 / x2` that stands for the base of the triangle *(the two coordinates that are hitting the circle)*. **But I'm not able to calculate the third one!**

```
triangle = {
    x1: image.width / 2 + radius * cos((rotationAngle * PI / 180)),
    y1: image.height / 2 + radius * sin((rotationAngle * PI / 180)),

    x2: image.width / 2 + radius * cos(((rotationAngle + triangleSize) * PI / 180)),
    y2: image.height / 2 + radius * sin(((rotationAngle + triangleSize) * PI / 180))
  }
```

Since I know that the opposite sides of the triangle are of equal length, I only have to calculate the last point. I know the theoretical path:

- Calculate gradient A of distance xy1/xy2
- Calculate the center M of distance xy1/xy2
- Calculate the normale from A with a certain length from the center M calculate = h of triangle

Nevertheless I have problems to implement it and hope that someone will help me. Thanks in advance.

[image: img]

Comment: As the formulas are now, the base of the triangle isn't horizontal when rotated 0 degrees - is this what you intended?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the height of the triangle, in the code segment below I have used a height of one tenth of the radius. I have also made it that the apex of the triangle is the part at exactly the rotation angle.

```
   triangle = {
   x3: image.width / 2 + 1.1 * radius * cos((rotationAngle * PI / 180)),
   y3: image.height / 2 + 1.1 * radius * sin((rotationAngle * PI / 180)),
   x1: image.width / 2 + radius * cos(((rotationAngle - 0.5 * triangleSize) * PI / 180)),
   y1: image.height / 2 + radius * sin(((rotationAngle - 0.5 * triangleSize) * PI / 180))
   x2: image.width / 2 + radius * cos(((rotationAngle + 0.5 * triangleSize) * PI / 180)),
   y2: image.height / 2 + radius * sin(((rotationAngle + 0.5 * triangleSize) * PI / 180))
      }
```

Comment: Note that if he wanted an equilateral triangle, the height follows from `triangleSize`

Comment: If you want it to scale with `trianglesize` you can replace `1.1` with

 `( 1 + trianglesize *  PI * sqrt(3) / 360 )`